# Why is '+=' used when assigning a function to an event?

Tags: c#, events

In C#, the event syntax is

```
event += onEvent
```

Why was it a better design choice while designing the C# language to use the `+=` operator instead of something like

```
event.AddHandler(...)
```

(or something similar)? Why is it used like this in the first place?

Comment: [Syntactic Sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar)

Comment: for more info [see this question's answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810562/binding-a-method-to-an-event-in-c-sharp-with-operator)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said by [Steve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/488397/steve) in the comments, the "+=" is just a syntactic sugar - syntax within a programming language that is designed to make things easier to read or to express